# Need help to resolve the join table issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables as following, the problem is that each book can only be own by one person.

```
Person_ID Book_ID
1           1          <<correct
2           1          << ERORR
```

How to change it in a way that each book can be own by many people?

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  private long id;
  .....
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
  }
 ....
}
```

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
public class Book {
 private long id;
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the relationship to ManyToMany

Answer (score 1):

You can Use annotation  @ManyToMany

```
@Entity
 public class Person {
 private long id;
.....
 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 public Set<Book> getBooks() {
      return books;
   }
 ....
  }
```